# What alternatives exist for Data Generation Plans for Visual Studio Express users?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, data-generation

I'm wondering if there is a good option for those of us using Express (or even Professional) editions without having to go outside the Visual Studio project (i.e. writing a ruby/perl/etc script to populate test/seed data).

If it helps I'm working on a C# .NET MVC 2 app within MS Web Developer 2010.

Comment: I've briefly searched for this in the past with no success and would be very interested to know if anything exists.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### [nBuilder](http://nbuilder.org/)

> What is it?
>
> Through a fluent, extensible
> interface, NBuilder allows you to
> rapidly create test data,
> automatically assigning values to
> properties and public fields that are
> of type of the built in .NET data
> types (e.g. ints and strings).
> NBuilder allows you to override for
> properties you are interested in using
> lambda expressions.
>
> NBuilder is an open source project,
> hosted on google code

There is an [episode of the Polymorphic Podcast](http://polymorphicpodcast.com/shows/nbuilder/) featuring a discussion with the creator of nBuilder.